# how to remove carriage return on Merged JSON Files using Azure Data Factory (ADF)

Tags: azure-data-factory

My requirement is to merge multiple JSON files as single JSON file using ADF tool and also remove multiple nested arrays and make it as single array.

sample Json file
[image]

1st file data:
[image]

2nd file data:
[image]

After merging these files using copy activity in ADF , I am getting Output as:
[image]

adding lines breaks between these two json files as shown below:
[image]

My expected output should remove carriage returns(\r,\n) between two files as shown below:
[image]

Please let me know any other solution to remove space between two Json files after merging them as single file using ADF

Comment: please don't use images to show code - you can embed the code directly in your question

Comment: is it fine with using any other notebook or script activity? Because using only copy activity you cannot remove `\r` and `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

**As JayashankarGS said we canty change row delimiter for Json in copy activity**.

Get metadata, for each, look up, and copy data activities are tools you may use to get around this problem and obtain the required outcome.

1. Use get metadata activity to obtain a list of the files in your directory first.
   [image]
2. Go through each JSON file that get metadata activity has returned and retrieve the data.
   [image]
3. Under foreach use lookup to get the data of each file.
   [image]
4. Next, add each item using an append variable activity to that a variable.
   [image]
5. Outside of the for each activity, utilize a set variable activity to retrieve the necessary information as a string.
   [image]

- Use any sample data (1 column, 1 row) from the source as delimited text in the final copy data activity. a new column should be created with value as the set variable.
  [image]
- Create a delimited text dataset for the sink dataset using the same specifications as in the figure below:
  [image]
- In mapping just keep Additional column.
  [image]
- It would produce the required outcome to run the pipeline. After the pipeline mentioned above is performed, the data would look like this.[image]

**My pipeline.json:**

```json
{
    "name": "pipeline2",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Get Metadata1",
                "type": "GetMetadata",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "Json3",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "fieldList": [
                        "childItems"
                    ],
                    "storeSettings": {
                        "type": "AzureBlobStorageReadSettings",
                        "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                    },
                    "formatSettings": {
                        "type": "JsonReadSettings"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "ForEach1",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Get Metadata1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "isSequential": true,
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Lookup1",
                            "type": "Lookup",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "source": {
                                    "type": "JsonSource",
                                    "storeSettings": {
                                        "type": "AzureBlobStorageReadSettings",
                                        "recursive": true,
                                        "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                                    },
                                    "formatSettings": {
                                        "type": "JsonReadSettings"
                                    }
                                },
                                "dataset": {
                                    "referenceName": "Json4",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                                    "parameters": {
                                        "filename": {
                                            "value": "@item().name",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "firstRowOnly": false
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Append variable1",
                            "type": "AppendVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Lookup1",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "merged",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@activity('Lookup1').output.value[0]",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Set variable1",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "ForEach1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "allmerged",
                    "value": {
                        "value": "@string(variables('merged'))",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Copy data1",
                "type": "Copy",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Set variable1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "DelimitedTextSource",
                        "additionalColumns": [
                            {
                                "name": "sample1",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@variables('allmerged')",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "storeSettings": {
                            "type": "AzureBlobStorageReadSettings",
                            "recursive": true,
                            "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                        },
                        "formatSettings": {
                            "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                        }
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "type": "DelimitedTextSink",
                        "storeSettings": {
                            "type": "AzureBlobStorageWriteSettings"
                        },
                        "formatSettings": {
                            "type": "DelimitedTextWriteSettings",
                            "quoteAllText": true,
                            "fileExtension": ".txt"
                        }
                    },
                    "enableStaging": false,
                    "translator": {
                        "type": "TabularTranslator",
                        "mappings": [
                            {
                                "source": {
                                    "name": "sample1",
                                    "type": "String"
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "type": "String",
                                    "physicalType": "String",
                                    "ordinal": 1
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "typeConversion": true,
                        "typeConversionSettings": {
                            "allowDataTruncation": true,
                            "treatBooleanAsNumber": false
                        }
                    }
                },
                "inputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "DelimitedText2",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }
                ],
                "outputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "DelimitedText3",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "variables": {
            "merged": {
                "type": "Array"
            },
            "allmerged": {
                "type": "String"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```